# bug when installing Angular-bootrstap

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

i am trying to install Angular bootrstap

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home

they say it is not compitable with the angular cli ver > 9

but they say

"
**If you have an Angular ≥ 9 CLI project, you could simply use our schematics to add ng-bootstrap library to it**
"

i saw this video https://youtu.be/CflqAqLLBEE?t=64

he is using this line

```
ng add @ng-bootstrap/schematics
```

for him it is working fine

but for me and for others in the comments it make a bug when compile with ng s -o

i think it is because he is using angular 9 and i am using angular 10

i know angular 11 just published i am still in the beginning of understanding the concepts :)

i will try to install it the regular way with the cdn and stuff but it is not come with the same benefits as ng bootstrap :(

screenshot of the bug

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r4dCncwwCl1SEDPy0FY_XyDtNWWdKSXH/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just create a new Angular Project and run

```
ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

In your app.module you can import the module you want,e.g.

```
import {NgbPaginationModule, NgbAlertModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [
    ...
    NgbDatepickerModule,
    NgbAlertModule,
  ],
  ...
})
```

And use it

```html
    <ngb-alert>hello word!</ngb-alert>
    <ngb-datepicker></ngb-datepicker>
    <ngb-rating rate="8"></ngb-rating>
```

My Angular version is 10.0.2

I just update to Angular 11

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --allow-dirty
```

And is working too